# How can I get keys from list of values?

Tags: javascript, list, underscore.js

I want to get keys based on my given list of values ..

here what i am looking for ,

this is my object,

```
my_obj = {
  "A": "a_id",
  "B": "b_id",
  "C": "c_id",
  "D": "d_id",
  "E": "status",
  "F": "start_time",
  "G": "end_time",
  "H": "count",
  "I": "task_desc",
  "J": "approved",
  "K": "point",
  "L": "complex",
  "M": "c_date",
  "N": "final_date"
}
my_val = ['c_date', 'final_date', 'my_due_date', 'start_date']
```

so, from the above `my_val` i want to get , `["M", "N"]`

i tried underscore `invert` to reverse my object to fetch... everything went good except return key instead value..

here what i tried,

```js
my_obj = {
  "A": "a_id",
  "B": "b_id",
  "C": "c_id",
  "D": "d_id",
  "E": "status",
  "F": "start_time",
  "G": "end_time",
  "H": "count",
  "I": "task_desc",
  "J": "approved",
  "K": "point",
  "L": "complex",
  "M": "c_date",
  "N": "final_date"
}
my_val = ['c_date', 'final_date', 'my_due_date', 'start_date']
out = _.filter(my_val, function(v) { return _.invert(my_obj)[v]})
console.log(out)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

```
_.invert(my_obj)[v]  - this gives me a `key` but inside filter didnt..
```

what is wrong in my code? how to get it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` to get an array of keys and filter it based on whether the corresponding value for each key is contained in the `my_val` array; [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) *determines whether an array includes a certain element* and returns a boolean value which suits nicely with `filter`:

```js
my_obj = {
  "A": "a_id",
  "B": "b_id",
  "C": "c_id",
  "D": "d_id",
  "E": "status",
  "F": "start_time",
  "G": "end_time",
  "H": "count",
  "I": "task_desc",
  "J": "approved",
  "K": "point",
  "L": "complex",
  "M": "c_date",
  "N": "final_date"
}
my_val = ['c_date', 'final_date', 'my_due_date', 'start_date']

console.log(
  Object.keys(my_obj).filter(k => my_val.includes(my_obj[k]))
)
```

Comment: @Psidom could you explain it? for deep understand? BTW nice answer thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```js
my_obj = {
      "A": "a_id",
      "B": "b_id",
      "C": "c_id",
      "D": "d_id",
      "E": "status",
      "F": "start_time",
      "G": "end_time",
      "H": "count",
      "I": "task_desc",
      "J": "approved",
      "K": "point",
      "L": "complex",
      "M": "c_date",
      "N": "final_date"
    }

my_val = ['c_date', 'final_date', 'my_due_date', 'start_date']

var output = [];

for (var i = 0; i < my_val.length; i++) {
  for (var key in my_obj) {
    if (my_obj[key] === my_val[i]) {
      output.push(key);
    }
  }
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a subset of the keys:

```
let subset = Object.keys(my_obj).filter((key, _) =>
  my_val.includes(my_obj[key])
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
my_obj = {
  "A": "a_id",
  "B": "b_id",
  "C": "c_id",
  "D": "d_id",
  "E": "status",
  "F": "start_time",
  "G": "end_time",
  "H": "count",
  "I": "task_desc",
  "J": "approved",
  "K": "point",
  "L": "complex",
  "M": "c_date",
  "N": "final_date"
}
let my_val = ['c_date', 'final_date', 'my_due_date', 'start_date']
let result = [];

for (let key in my_obj)
{
  for (let i = 0; i < my_val.length; i++)
  {
    if (my_obj[key] == my_val[i])
    {
      result.push(key);
    }
  }

}

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `filter()` incorrectly. That method requires the callback function to return a boolean, but here you return a string. If you want to return a string (the key) for each entry in `my_val`, you should use `map()` instead.

Comment: here i used underscore filter not a native one